# Apache Netbeans IDE 12.0 doesn't open

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

when I launch netbeans, it's loading and then it doesn't launch nothing and if I want to reopen it, it just shows me this: http://prntscr.com/uoo9aa
I tried to uninstall it, but it said I have running program, so I deleted files and tried to install it again, but it didn't help.
I'm installing Apache Netbeans IDE 12.0 with jdk-14.0.2.

Comment: Try launching it from `cmd` and see if there's any error on the terminal.

Comment: It shows me just this: http://prntscr.com/uookhl

Comment: Does your problem solved?